# Является ли неявное преобразование типов атомарной операцией?

Tags: c#

```
object o = 42;
```

Атомарны ли такое и все другие неявные преобразования типов?

Comment: А в чём практический смысл рассуждать об атомарности преобразования типов?

Comment: Судя по ответам/комментам к вопросу 10-летней выдержки на основном SO [C# object type - atomicity of assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396303/), присваивание ссылок является атомарной операцией (в отличие от присваивания "длинных" примитивных типов `long`, `ulong`, `double`, `decimal`).

Comment: @NowhereMan но вопрос не про присваивание, а про преобразование)

Comment: В данном случае неявное преобразование (boxing) происходит при присваивании

Comment: До присваивания или после?

Comment: @Грузчик посмотрите описание команы box, там перед вызовом самой команды значение копируется на стек

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не явное преобразоаание (implicit conversion) по сути вызов статического метода, поэтомы быть атомарным никак не может. В вашем примере производитмя boxing значения 42, т.е. выделение в куче места под хранение инта с последующей инициализацией значением 42, такое действо не атомарно.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы сослаться на этот метод здесь https://source.dot.net/?

Comment: @Грузчик - кода упаковки в исходниках фреймворка вы не найдёте, это превращается на этапе компиляции в msil команду box (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.box). А если вас интересует механизм implicit conversion тогда смотрите вот сюда https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Comment: По правде говоря компилятор может оптимизировать код так что конвертация может стать атомарной, но это не касается случаев с упаковкой (boxing) и не является правилом